# How can i define Javascript variable to Session in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, variables, session

My problem is that I have several a tag and a javascript. When click the a tag, JavaScript works and get the tag value. It's okey but I want to assign this javascript variable to session or asp.net's variable. Because a href will goes another page and I need a href value. Also a href inside a SQL loop.

How will I do ? Is there another way without JavaScript ?

Comment: What is "a href inside a SQL loop" ?

Comment: There is a SQL Loop. I mean while loop. Inside the loop, There is a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `QueryString`. No need for any javascript.

```
<a href="page.aspx?id=1">Click</a>
```

In you .net code:

```
var Id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Comment: Use `int.TryParse` to deal with potential malformed requests